# Binomial Coefficient Bounded by Polynomial Decay

Tags: real-analysis, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

The goal is to show that,

$\frac{M}{k^2}<{n \choose k}$,

where, M > 0, n is in (0, 1), and k is a positive integer. I have tried a handful of different strategies to solve this, but I havn't made any progress whatsoever in any of my strategies. I feel like I am missing something. When I plot this, this does hold true though. Is there any relations I am missing that would assist in this?

Comment: This is missing some quantifiers. It is not true for all choices of M, n, k.